# Change timeAgo to expire system

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

In my current project, I use an extension that shows how long ago, a post was posted. Using this extension:

```
extension NSDate {
    var timeAgo: String {
        let minute = 60
        let hour = 60 * minute
        let day = 24 * hour
        let secondsAgo = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(self))
        if secondsAgo < 0            { return  "later"                           }
        if secondsAgo == 0           { return "now"                              }
        if secondsAgo == 1           { return "1 second ago"                     }
        if secondsAgo < minute       { return "\(secondsAgo) seconds ago"        }
        if secondsAgo < (2 * minute) { return "1 minute ago"                     }
        if secondsAgo < hour         { return "\(secondsAgo/minute) minutes ago" }
        if secondsAgo < 2 * hour     { return "1 hour ago"                       }
        if secondsAgo < day          { return "\(secondsAgo / hour) hours ago"   }
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yy"
        return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}
```

This is how I set the uploaded timestamp to the post:

```
imageCell?.uploadedTimeLabel.text = createdAt[indexPath.item].timeAgo
```

But how can I make a expire system instead? That the user can set expires in: 24 hours, and in the post, it will say something like "Expires in 10 hours", "Expires in 8 minutes" etc..? And when the the expire reach 0, the post gets deleted. Any ideas?

Comment: you have post's posted timestamp right ?

Comment: if yes, then subtract post's posted timestamp from current time

Comment: @sheshnath - Yes, all the posts says something like: "5 minutes ago", "1 hour ago". How I set the timestamp is added in the question. How do you mean I should do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have partially coded, with little to do list mention in code comment.

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm a"];
    [format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    NSDictionary *dictPost1=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"post one",@"14/03/2016 04:15 pm"] forKeys:@[@"postName",@"timeStapmp"]];

     NSDictionary *dictPost2=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"post two",@"14/03/2016 03:15 pm"] forKeys:@[@"postName",@"timeStapmp"]];

    NSArray *arrposts=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:dictPost1,dictPost2, nil];
    for (NSDictionary *dictPost in arrposts) {
        NSDate *postedDate=[format dateFromString:[dictPost objectForKey:@"timeStapmp"]];
        NSLog(@"difference=%f in miliseconds",[postedDate timeIntervalSinceNow]);
        //To-do 1.convert millisecond difference into hour and mintue
        //To-do 2. subtract converted hour from 10, reaming time to expire
    }
```